# Backup / Restore Titanium Backup's labels

Tags: titanium-backup

When I move to a new phone, I only want to install my previously installed user apps.

I use a label to identify which apps are currently installed, vs old ones, vs system apps.

How can I backup and restore my TiBk labels?

Answer (score 1):

From the old ROM, save a copy of `/data/data/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup/databases/custom`.

- Settings->Apps, force stop TiBak, wipe its data.
- Run TiBk (this creates an initial set of databases). Check busybox, etc are OK.
- Again: Settings->Apps, stop TitBak.
- Replace `/data/data/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup/databases/custom` with the copy from the old ROM
- Restart TiBk; profit.

[Credit](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=11475558)